# Style posts which can vary in number?

Tags: php, css

Forewarning: I am bad at CSS.

Hello,
I am working on a little message board which displays the 3 most recent posts.
I would also like the user to choose how many posts are displayed on one screen,
say 5 or 10 posts.

Currently I have it so that all posts are printed out in this manner:

```
while ($i < $d){
// $d is entered by the user to determine how many posts are to be displayed.
    if ($i == $id_Max){
        echo "Reached last known post.";
        break;
    }

    $query2 = $con->prepare(
    "SELECT postName, postPath FROM " . $table .
    " WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id-".$i.") FROM " . $table . ")"
    );
    $query2->execute();
    $result2 = $query2->fetch();
    $path = $result2["postPath"];
    $file = file_get_contents($path);

    echo "<article class = 'entry'>";

    echo "<section id = 'entryTitle'>";
    echo $result2["postName"] . "<br />";
    echo "</section>";

    echo $file;
    echo "<br />";

    echo "</article>";

    $i++;
}
```

So, each post that is printed has the class of `entry`. With this I gave each post a border, but I want to make it so that there is a space of about 5px between them.
I set their `position: relative` and `top: 5px` but it only takes effect on the top most entry and moves them all down by 5px from the very top of the page.

Essentially, I want to have something work globally with out having to write out something for each possible post. `#entry1`, `#entry2`...

I am look not really for how to do this specific thing, but more of something that I can learn from to apply in future things.

Thanks,
- Michael Mitchell

(If I was not clear, please tell me and I will attempt to explain better.)

Comment: Did you try giving `article.entry` a `margin` with CSS, e.g. `article.entry { margin: 10px 0; }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things I see going on wrong here.

First of all, spacing between elements is typically handled with margins:

```
/* all .entry elements */
.entry { margin-top: 10px }
/* all but the first .entry elements */
.entry + .entry { margin-top: 10px }
```

Second, it looks like you are making multiple requests to the database when you don't really need to.  The query you want looks like this:

```
SELECT postName, postPath FROM tablename ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT ?
```

This will give you a list of the top entries that you can iterate through and is *much* faster than making multiple requests.  If you want the number of entries return to be configurable, make absolutely sure you are sanitizing/escaping the value.

Comment: Thanks!
I have a bit of another question while we are at it.
What does the > operator do in CSS
like `.mainPosts > #mainPostsHeader {}`
What specific things can it do/alter?

Comment: The `>` selector is "direct descendant", meaning `#mainPostsHeader` is a child of `.mainPosts` and not a grandchild or great-grandchild (if you wanted any descendant, use a space: `.mainPosts #mainPostsHeader`).  Typically, you won't target an ID that way because they're supposed to be unique to the page (if you have multiple, it can cause unexpected results in JS).

Answer (score 0):

The 'top' css property generally only applies to elements with a position of absolute.  You will want the entry class have have:

```
margin-bottom:5px;
```

or

```
margin-top:5px;
```

I don't think you need the `position:relative` property to do this either.